# Accessing pointer to pointer object in another class

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

How can i access the whellno of the Model object in Car class?

```
class Car {
    private:
    int id;
    Model** model; 
    };


class Model {
private:
string text;
int whellno; 
};
```

in this constructor, i need to access whellno of the Model object, however can not find a proper solution.i know that , accessing private member of a class in different class is forbidden.

```
Car::Car(const Car& rhs, int whell1, intwhell2)
```

Comment: What's the reason for the double-pointer `model`? Why do you think you need even a single pointer?

Comment: The proper solution would probably be to add a public `int getWhellno() const {return whellno;}` method to the `Model` class, and then call that method to get the value.   (either that, or perhaps move your calling code out of a method in `Car` and into a method in `Model`, if it fits better there)

Comment: For setting the member variable of `Model`, since you're in the `Car` constructor, you could use a *constructor initializer list* to initialize the `Model` object, using a suitable constructor.